# Let A and B be $n × n$ invertible symmetric matrices, and suppose that A and B commute, show $A^{-1}B$ is symmetric.

Tags: linear-algebra

I tried starting from any of the given things and multiplying etc.. but all seemed blocked roads, can anyone help/give a hint?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ commute then $A^{-1}$ and $B$ commute as well. The rest is easy.

Comment: Thank you, solved it then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A^{-1}B)^t=B^t(A^{-1})^t=B(A^t)^{-1}=BA^{-1}$

$AB=BA$ implies that $ABA^{-1}=BAA^{-1}=B$ and $A^{-1}ABA^{-1}=BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$.

We deduce that $(A^{-1}B)^t=BA^{-1}=A^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 0):

another approach: first prove that $A^k B$ is symmetric for natural number $k$.  Then prove the obvious that a linear combination of symmetric matrices is symmetric.  It follows that $A^{-1}B$ is symmetric Cayley Hamilton.